# How to use the STL to take a vector of structs and turn it into a vector of the structs elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

How can I use the c++'s algorithm's and iterators libraries to achieve the same thing?

```
std::vector<float> transformVectorOfVec3ToVectorofFloats(const std::vector<vector3> & p_vec3Vector)
{
  std::vector<float> l_floatVector;
  l_floatVector.resize(p_vec3Vector.size());

  for(auto m_vec3 : p_vec3Vector)
  {
    l_floatVector.push_back(m_vec3.x);
    l_floatVector.push_back(m_vec3.y);
    l_floatVector.push_back(m_vec3.z);
  }
}
```

something like this

```
//std::transform(p_vec3Vector.begin(), p_vec3Vector.end(), l_floatVector.begin(), []()->float); ???
```

vector3 is just a class with 3 float member variables.

Comment: I know someone will have a nicer whiz-bang solution, but you could use `std::accumulate` to return the new vector in one line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `vector.insert()` and the initializer list to shorten the loop:

```
std::vector<float> transformVectorOfVec3ToVectorofFloats(const std::vector<vector3> & p_vec3Vector)
{
  std::vector<float> l_floatVector;
  for(auto m_vec3 : p_vec3Vector)
      l_floatVector.insert(l_floatVector.end(), {m_vec3.x,, m_vec3.y, m_vec3.z});
  return l_floatVector;
}
```

You could also use `std::accumulate` to remove all hand-written loops:

```
std::vector<float> transformVectorOfVec3ToVectorofFloats(const std::vector<vector3> & p_vec3Vector)
{
    return std::accumulate(p_vec3Vector.begin(), p_vec3Vector.end(), 
                           std::vector<float>(), []
                           (std::vector<float>& total, const vector3& v) 
                           { total.insert(total.end(), {v.x, v.y, v.z}); return total;});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

std::for_each is an alternative to std::accumulate:

```
std::for_each(std::begin(p_vec3Vector), std::end(p_vec3Vector),
  [&l_floatVector](auto e) {
     l_floatVector.insert(std::end(l_floatVector), {e.x, e.y, e.z});
  });
```

Comment: Thank you so much Luis this is really tight code :)